# Reading access disruption: tree was 0xAE0A74BF

Tags: c

I'm currently finishing my college project, and the only thing left is implementing branch deletion. But the code crashes with this error.

```
void treeprintprime(tNode* tree) {

FILE* lasttree = fopen("lasttree.txt", "a");

if (tree != NULL) {
    fprintf(lasttree, "%d ", tree->key); //error happens here
    treeprintprime(tree->right);
    treeprintprime(tree->left);
    cout << tree->key << " ";
}
fclose(lasttree);
}

void delete_node() {
int key;
FILE* lasttree = fopen("lasttree.txt", "r+");
struct tNode* root = NULL;
while (fscanf(lasttree, "%d", &key) == 1)
{
    root = addNode(key, root);
}
printf("What element and his subtree do you want to delete? \n");
printf(">> ");
fclose(lasttree);
key = scanfunction(); 
searchtodeleteNode(key, root);
treeprintprime(root);
freemem(root);
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
}
```

I've changed the code.

Comment: You are closing the file two times `fclose(lasttree);` instead you should have closed it in `treeprintprime` function.

Comment: In general, a stack traceback would be nice.  Be sure to show us the line# the stack trace points to.  ALSO: Q: Why are you doing `fclose(lasttree);` twice???

Comment: Isn't this C++ but mixing `cout <<` with `printf`? You should be consistent.

Comment: I've changed it, but error did not go anywhere.

Comment: @kiranBiradar should i erase one of them or both?

Answer (score 1):

The function `treeprintprime` is a recursive function.

It opens a file, appends the key value, and then recurses. If it was a NULL node, the file was opened for no purpose. And only after the recursion has returned, does it close the file.

So you have opened multiple (same) files which you don't close until later.

In the absence of code that can be tried, I suggest opening and closing the file immediately before and after appending, like

```
void treeprintprime(tNode* tree) {
    if (tree != NULL) {
        FILE* lasttree = fopen("lasttree.txt", "a"); // move the open function to here
        // ** note check result of fopen() **
        fprintf(lasttree, "%d ", tree->key);
        fclose(lasttree);                            // move the close function to here
        treeprintprime(tree->right);
        treeprintprime(tree->left);
        cout << tree->key << " ";                    // note this is C++ in tagged C code
    }
}
```

But even better would be to open the file before traversing the tree, and closing it afterwards.